# 'as I've done something I guess something'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm kind of confused whether the following sentence is correct or not. I'm specifically not sure about the *As I've done something I guess that..* part.

> As I've completed all lectures, all quizzes and the final project as
>   well I guess the course is over for me. Thus, I'd like to thank you
>   for your time...

I'm not aware of any grammar rule the sentence would brake but I wanted to be 100 % sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing especially wrong with the sentence as speech goes. However, in writing, it would be kinder on your reader to introduce a few commas for a clearer parse:

> As I’ve completed all lectures, all quizzes, and the final project as well, I guess the course is over for me.